# Facebook Graph API: Comments from data is missing

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to retrieve the poster's name and profile photo when fetching the comments from a live feed or a saved video on a business page. With some google I've found that I need to pass a page_access_token to the request. I've retrieved the access token from the `/me/accounts` blade and adding it to my request (TypeScript):

```
this.facebook.api(`/${this.facebook_video_id}/comments?fields=id,message,created_time,from&access_token=${this.page_access_token}`)
```

This is not working and no from property is found on each comment object. My permissions request includes the following options:

```
const options: LoginOptions = {
  scope: 'public_profile,email',
  return_scopes: true,
  enable_profile_selector: true
};
```

Comment: Is your app live? In dev mode this is definitively not supposed to work, there you should get this for users with a role in the app only.

Comment: @04FS No, the app is not live and still under heavy construction. Would I need to get the application audit to have the `from` field populated?

Comment: Test it with users that have a role in the app first.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: which permissions did you used?

Comment: No, I was never able to resolve it. I'm pretty sure the FB API removed that functionality.